# How to import $\LaTeX$ matrices into Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, import, expression-manipulation, latex

I have a lot of $\LaTeX$ matrices, and I want to find their eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I tried to import them to Mathematica with:

```
ToExpression["[MATRIX PASTED FROM LATEX]",TeXForm]
```

This method worked for everything I tried until now, as long as it wasn't a matrix. For some reason, Mathematica thinks of the matrix as some kind of "ExpressionCell" That I know nothing of.

Here is an example of this problem:

Input:

```
ToExpression["\\begin{matrix}{0} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{\\sqrt{2}} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{0} & {\\sqrt{2}} & {0}
\\end{matrix}", TeXForm]
```

Output: (I converted it to InputForm so you can see the problem)

```
ExpressionCell[TraditionalForm[{{TextCell[Row[{ , TextCell[0, InlineFormula],  }]], 
 TextCell[Row[{ , TextCell[0, InlineFormula],  }]], 
 TextCell[Row[{ , TextCell[0, InlineFormula],  }]]}, 
{TextCell[Row[{ , ExpressionCell[2, InlineFormula],  }]], 
 TextCell[Row[{ , TextCell[0, InlineFormula],  }]], 
 TextCell[Row[{ , TextCell[0, InlineFormula],  }]]}, 
{TextCell[Row[{ , TextCell[0, InlineFormula],  }]], 
 TextCell[Row[{ , ExpressionCell[2, InlineFormula],  }]], 
 TextCell[Row[{ , TextCell[0, InlineFormula],  }]]}}]]
```

When I ran the code the matrix **looks** fine - like a Matrix. But Mathematica just doesn't think of it as a matrix, and therefor can't find it's eigenvalues (or do any kind of calculations).

I'm stuck here.  Does anyone how to input matrices into Mathemtica?

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I found that I'm not the only one stuck with this problem:

[Another poor user from Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-input-LaTeX-code-directly-in-Mathematica)

Comment: My WinEdt fails with compiling your \\ begin{matrix}{0} & {0} & {0}\\ \\
{\\ sqrt{2}} & {0} & {0}\\ \\
{0} & {\\ sqrt{2}} & {0}
\\ end{matrix}. Is it OK?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming the OP wants `"\\sqrt{2}"` to turn into the equivalent of `$\sqrt{2}$` or $\sqrt{2}$, which would `Sqrt[2]` in *Mathematica*.  The command `ToExpression[s, TeXForm]` does not seem to handle the square roots, when they are embedded in a matrix, as in the OP's string.  The matrix format of TeX is so straightforward that one can split it up into a list of lists almost on the fly:

```
stripLaTeXCommand[cmd_] := StringDelete[cmd ~~ "{" ~~ Except["}"] ... ~~ "}"];
split[pat_] := StringSplit[#, pat] &;
texToExp = Function[s, ToExpression[s, TeXForm], Listable];

"\\begin{matrix}{0} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{\\sqrt{2}} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{0} & {\\sqrt{2}} & {0}
\\end{matrix}"   //
   stripLaTeXCommand["\\begin" | "\\end"] //
   StringTrim    //
   split["\\\\"] //
   split["&"]    //
   texToExp
(*  {{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[2], 0, 0}, {0, Sqrt[2], 0}}  *)
```

Remarks: (1) I'd say mishandling the square roots in a matrix is a bug. (2) ***Caveat:*** `ToExpression["\\begin{matrix}{0}", TeXForm]` and `texToExp["\\begin{matrix}{0}"]` would sometimes return `$Failed` (good) and sometimes seemingly get stuck in an infinite loop (bad).  I had to kill the kernel (but not the front end) to get back control of *Mathematica*.

Comment: As far as I can see, this works for all of my matrices. Thanks!

Comment: @DeadlosZ You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

From your `InputForm` example, we can see that each row has the same structure.  Namely each row has the form

```
TextCell[Row[List[" ", TextCell[element_, "InlineFormula"], " "]]]
```

or

```
TextCell[Row[List[" ", ExpressionCell[element_, "InlineFormula"], " "]]]
```

where `element` is the number in that entry of the matrix.

Then we can take advantage of this and simply replace each outermost `TextCell` with the non-string element itself with

```
TextCell[Row[List[" ", (TextCell | ExpressionCell)[element_, "InlineFormula"], " "]]] :> ToExpression@element
```

Then we still have the pesky `ExpressionCell[TraditionalForm[...]]` to take care of with a simple part specification.

In the case of your example, this turns out to be

```
mat = ToExpression["\\begin{matrix}{0} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{\\sqrt{2}} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{0} & {\\sqrt{2}} & {0}
\\end{matrix}", TeXForm]

mat /. TextCell[Row[List[" ", (TextCell | ExpressionCell)[element_, "InlineFormula"], " "]]] :> ToExpression@element
%[[1, 1]]
FullForm@%
```

> {{0,0,0},{2,0,0},{0,2,0}}
>
> List[List[0,0,0],List[2,0,0],List[0,2,0]]

And the beauty of this approach is that it readily generalizes (as far as I can tell).  For example

```
ToExpression["\\begin{matrix}{0} & {0} & {0} & {2} \\\\
{\\sqrt{2}} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\\\
{0} & {\\sqrt{2}} & {0} & {7}
\\end{matrix}", TeXForm]

% /. TextCell[Row[List[" ", (TextCell | ExpressionCell)[element_, "InlineFormula"], " "]]] :> ToExpression@element

%[[1, 1]]//FullForm
```

> List[List[0,0,0,2],List[2,0,0,0],List[0,2,0,7]]

Comment: What happened to the `"\\sqrt"`?

Comment: This solution looks perfect, but it does looks like the sqrt disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
SetAttributes[toexpr, Listable];
toexpr[str_] := ToExpression[str, TeXForm]

importlatexmat[str_] := 
 toexpr@ImportString[str, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {"\\\\", "&"}, 
   "Numeric" -> False]

importlatexmat@"{0} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{\\sqrt{2}} & {0} & {0}\\\\
{0} & {\\sqrt{2}} & {0}"
```