# Is it possible to convert a matrix in $\LaTeX$ format to Mathematica input?

Tags: import, latex, conversion

Is it possible to do this already in version 11.3?  For example, I want to draw a graph

```
P = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P];
gr = Graph[proc, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> P[[i, j]]}]
```

by just copying the matrix

```
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
```

The answer of xzczd worked for the previous matrix, but all hell broke loose when I switched to fractions.

```
P = ImportString["\\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\\\
  0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{4} & \\frac{1}{4} \\\\
  \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & \\frac{1}{2} \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \\frac{1}{4} & \\frac{3}{4}", "Table", 
  "FieldSeparators" -> {"\\", "&"}]
P // MatrixForm
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P];
gr = Graph[proc, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> P[[i, j]]}]

{{"frac{1}{2} ", 0, " ", "frac{1}{2} ", 0, 0}, {0, " ", "frac{1}{2} ",
   0, " ", "frac{1}{4} ", " ", "frac{1}{4} "}, {"frac{1}{2} ", 0, " ",
   "frac{1}{2} ", 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, " ", "frac{1}{2} ", " ", 
  "frac{1}{2} "}, {0, 0, 0, " ", "frac{1}{4} ", " ", "frac{3}{4}"}}
```

It seems copy-pasting latex only works for experts

Comment: Why not copy-paste and replace `&` with `,` and `\\ ` with `}{` ?

Comment: I've updated my solution to make it handle the new added example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
SetAttributes[toexpr, Listable];
toexpr[str_] := ToExpression[str, TeXForm]

importlatexmat[str_] := 
 toexpr@ImportString[str, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> {"\\\\", "&"}, 
   "Numeric" -> False]

"0& 0& 1 \\\\
1& 0& 0 \\\\
0& 1& 0" // importlatexmat

"\\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\\\
  0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{4} & \\frac{1}{4} \\\\
  \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & \\frac{1}{2} \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \\frac{1}{4} & \\frac{3}{4}" // importlatexmat
```

Another approach is to use functions in Michael E2's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201280/1871):

```
"\\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & 1 & 0
\\end{pmatrix}" // stripLaTeXCommand["\\begin" | "\\end"] // StringTrim // 
   split["\\\\"] // split["&"] // texToExp

"\\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\\\
  0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{4} & \\frac{1}{4} \\\\
  \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \\frac{1}{2} & \\frac{1}{2} \\\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \\frac{1}{4} & \\frac{3}{4}" // StringTrim // split["\\\\"] // 
  split["&"] // texToExp
```

Comment: The first approach worked :)